# Error matching points and legend in R plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a plot in R. However, I am not being able to match the legend and the points. My code is:

```
G is a matrix and I want the color and simbols (pch) based on the G row names.


pdf(file = "PCA.pdf", width = 8, height = 8)
plot(pca$x[,2], pca$x[,1], 
main="Principal components", xlab="First principal component", ylab="Second principal component",
col= ifelse(row.names(G) == "RL", "black", ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOAUS", "red", 
ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOCAN", "pink",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "AL", "green",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "EN", "blue",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "LN", "yellow",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "TO", "orange",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "NU", "purple",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "CA", "grey", "white"))))))))), pch= ifelse(row.names(G) == "RL", 1, ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOAUS", 2, 
ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOCAN", 3,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "AL", 4,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "EN", 5,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "LN", 6,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "TO", 7,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "NU", 8,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "CA", 9, 10))))))))))

legend("bottomright", unique(rownames(G)), col= ifelse(row.names(G) == "RL", "black", ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOAUS", "red", 
ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOCAN", "pink",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "AL", "green",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "EN", "blue",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "LN", "yellow",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "TO", "orange",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "NU", "purple",
ifelse(row.names(G) == "CA", "grey", "white"))))))))), pch= ifelse(row.names(G) == "RL", 1, ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOAUS", 2, 
ifelse(row.names(G) == "BOCAN", 3,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "AL", 4,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "EN", 5,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "LN", 6,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "TO", 7,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "NU", 8,
ifelse(row.names(G) == "CA", 9, 10))))))))), ncol=3, cex=0.7)
dev.off()
```

The plot that I am getting is:
Any help in how to get a nicer plot would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about: `plot(pca$x[,2], pca$x[,1], col=as.numeric(factor(row.names(G)))); legend("bottomright", unique(rownames(G)); col=as.numeric(unique(row.names(G))))`

Comment: Thanks @jbaums . However, it still doesn't not show the points in the legend (only the letters). I supposed I need to include the fill function. But it doesn't work well.

Comment: Specify `pch` in the same manner: `plot(pca$x[,2], pca$x[,1], col=as.numeric(factor(row.names(G))), pch=as.numeric(factor(row.names(G)))); legend("bottomright", unique(rownames(G)); col=as.numeric(unique(factor(row.names(G)))), pch=as.numeric(unique(factor(row.names(G)))))`

Comment: Thanks @jbaums . It works great now. Sorry it is my first time doing this. I was trying for so long. :-) Cheers.